# Using jquery to set a content area to height of page with sticky footer

Tags: jquery, html, height, footer

http://www.playerspace.com/index.cfm/action/aboutus

I am using jquery to set a sticky footer where the content doesn't extend below the fold.

If I didn't there would be space under the footer to the bottom of the browser window.

Unfortunately on pages where this takes place, like the link included above, the content area has a gap between the bottom of the container and the sticky footer.

Can anyone tell me how I can set the height of the white content container to meet the footer with jquery on page load?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without jQuery.

Set the container you wish to fill the whole page `height: 100%` along with all that containers parents including `body`, and `html`.

**Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/**

Comment: Ive set it to 100%. No effect.

Comment: set every parent of the container to 100%

Comment: nm i got it:  if($('#home_page_footer').length >0 ){ 
  var footer = $("#home_page_footer");
  var pos = footer.position();
  var height = $(window).height();
  height = height - pos.top;
  height = height - footer.height();
  if (height < 500 && height > 0) {
   $("#content").height($(window).height()-258);                          
  } 
 }